# xpath on Google spreadsheet "Internal import error"

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I can't quite get my head around something that should just work...

```
=IMPORTXML("https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/killID/38382331/xml/","//victim/@characterName")
```

When i put that into Google docs it results a "internal import error", I ran the same xPath through 6 online xPath testers and they all got the correct result.

I know the data is coming through as the currentTime node works just fine on the sheet.

Am I being dumb or am I missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well cause there XPath engine is buggy as hell...this works:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/killID/38382331/xml/","//victim/@charactername")
```

...also it shouldn't, there XPath engine only likes lowercase attributes...